# (Microbit) Player position resets after function completes

Tags: python

I've been working on a program for the Microbit inspired by some basic blocks script I saw a few years back. The functionality of the AI controlled pixel and the player controlled pixel work as intended--which one annoying, and game breaking bug--the player ship resets to its spawn position whenever the AI ship completes its function.

I suspect this is because I have an assigned position for the ship in the beginning of the code, where it is then modified in the function itself. Removing this results in an error where a variable is not referenced--however, I cannot leave the problem alone. I welcome any guidance. The code is below.

```
from microbit import *
import random

enemyXpos = 4
playerXpos = 2

while True: 

display.set_pixel(enemyXpos,0,4)
display.set_pixel(playerXpos,4,6)

def laser(laserXpos, laserYpos):
laserXpos = playerXpos
laserYpos = 3

for i in range (4):
display.set_pixel(laserXpos,laserYpos,9)
if laserYpos > 0:
display.set_pixel(laserXpos,laserYpos,0)
laserYpos -= 1
display.set_pixel(laserXpos,laserYpos,9)
if laserYpos == 0 and laserXpos == enemyXpos:
display.show(all_booms, delay=200)
score = score + 1
continue
elif laserYpos == 0:
display.set_pixel(bombXpos,bombYpos,0)
laserYpos = newlaserYpos
sleep (200) 

def enemy_left(enemyXpos, playerXpos):
enemyXpos = 4
for i in range (4):
display.clear() 
enemyXpos -= 1
display.set_pixel(enemyXpos,0,4)
display.set_pixel(playerXpos,4,6)
if button_a.is_pressed() and button_b.is_pressed():
laser(laserXpos,laserYpos)
elif button_a.is_pressed() and playerXpos > 0:
playerXpos -= 1
elif button_b.is_pressed() and playerXpos < 4:
playerXpos += 1 
sleep(200)

def enemy_right(enemyXpos, playerXpos):
enemyXpos = 0
for i in range (4):
display.clear()
enemyXpos += 1
display.set_pixel(enemyXpos,0,4)
display.set_pixel(playerXpos,4,6)
if button_a.is_pressed() and button_b.is_pressed():
laser(laserXpos,laserYpos)
elif button_a.is_pressed() and playerXpos > 0:
playerXpos -= 1
elif button_b.is_pressed() and playerXpos < 4:
playerXpos += 1
sleep(200)

enemy_left(enemyXpos, playerXpos)
enemy_right(enemyXpos, playerXpos)
```